# Confused about self in derived class and relation to base class member variables

Tags: python, class

In the code sample below I am using self.number in the derived class, b, and number is defined in a (the base class).  If a data member is defined in this way in a base class, is it always accessible to any derived class?

I am using Python 2.7.  Is this the correct way to refer to base object member variables?

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        print "a __init__ called with number=", number

    def printme(self):
        print self.number



class b(a):
    def __init__(self, fruit):
        super(b, self).__init__(1)
        self.fruit = fruit
        print "b __init__ called with fruit=", fruit

    def printme(self):
        print self.number


cl1 = a(1)
cl1.printme()

cl2 = b("apple")
cl2.printme()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you do something in a subclass that would eliminate it, then yes.  Attributes assigned to Python objects are just added to the object's `__dict__` (except for the relatively rare cases where slots is used or `__setattr__` is overridden to do something non-standard), and the implicit first argument to a bound member method is going to be the same for methods originating from the child or the parent class.  Vanilla instance attributes (though not methods or class attributes) are not bound in any way to a specific class definition, only to the object instance to which they belong.

The one caveat to that statement is attributes with names beginning with double underscores.  They'll still be added to the `__dict__` and accessible, but they will have been name mangled, so will only be accessible outside the defining class if retrieved using the mangled transformation of the attribute name.

Comment: The same goes for methods, too, so the redefinition of `printme()` in `class b` is superfluous, as currently written.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Well, methods are associated to their defining class, not to the instance that calls them, but in this case, they do function similarly.